# “One martyr more in heaven and one hero less on earth”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[war and peace](https://books.google.jo/books?id=WX7yCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1926&dq=after%20the%20murder%20of%20the%20duc%20there%20was%20one%20martyr%20more%20in%20heaven&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdra3BpZ3XAhUhKcAKHbm6DcsQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=after%20the%20murder%20of%20the%20duc%20there%20was%20one%20martyr%20more%20in%20heaven&f=false)

> after the murder of the duc **there was one martyr more in heaven and one hero less on earth**.

Confused about the meaning that the text could imply.

Does it give the meaning that there is more than one martyr in heaven, and at least one hero on earth?

Comment: To me it's not a particularly good translation. It should be "one hero FEWER on earth"

Comment: @SimonH, just bear in mind that "Less has always been used in English with countable nouns." with records dating back to 888 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fewer_vs._less)

Comment: What does Alfred the Great know about English!?  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..after the murder of the duc there was **one martyr more in heaven and one hero less on earth.**

This simply means that after the duc's death, he is assumed to be in heaven, having died a heroic death during a battle, alongside many other martyrs. Since he is no more, as he was martyred in the war, one can say that he can no longer be referred to as a '*hero*' on the battlefield.

So when you look at the whole picture, the duc's passing would mean that the battalion lost a hero, and will only be remembered as a hero, that he was, when he was alive.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Could u tell me please why the writer didn’t put a comma between “duc and there”?

Comment: That might depend on the content that comes before the extract you have provided. Since the content you provided is only a part of the sentence, it is difficult deduce anything further.

Comment: But i have provided my question with a resource, you can just click on it.

Comment: Since this is a translated version, it is also quite possible that the punctuation was overseen by the translating author.

Answer (score 0):

The duc is both a martyr and a hero. When he died, he left the earth (because he died), and entered heaven. This gave heaven one more martyr (namely, the duc), and earth one less hero (because the duc was now gone).

As for your question: *Does it give the meaning that there is more than one martyr in heaven, and at least one hero on earth?* I would say, "not really." You aren't supposed to read the original and make inferences on the number of heros and martyrs on heaven and on earth; you just know that, in dying, the duc left one less hero on the earth has he was transported to heaven.